# How to limit number of rows?

Tags: css

For mobile version need to show only 4 rows of 9. How to solve it with css?
On desktop will show 9 rows of 9.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
main {
  padding: 0 20px;
  width: 100%; 
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr)); 
  grid-gap: 1em;
}

article {
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  background: black
}
```

```html
<main>
  <article>1</article>
  <article>2</article>
  <article>3</article>
  <article>4</article>
  <article>5</article>
  <article>6</article>
  <article>7</article>
  <article>8</article>
  <article>9</article>
</main>
```

Comment: So basically you want to get rid of 5 rows in mobile version?

Comment: I need to show only first 4 rows

Comment: Please do not just include a link to a pen, you could easily set this up with a snippet. I have updated this for you on this question

Comment: This can be achieved with n-th child https://css-tricks.com/useful-nth-child-recipies/

Answer (score 1):

You can do like below:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
main {
  padding: 0 20px;
  width: 100%; 
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr)); 
  grid-gap: 1em;
}

article {
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  background: black
}

@media (max-width:800px) {
  article:nth-child(n + 6) {
    display:none;
  }
}
```

```html
<main>
  <article>1</article>
  <article>2</article>
  <article>3</article>
  <article>4</article>
  <article>5</article>
  <article>6</article>
  <article>7</article>
  <article>8</article>
  <article>9</article>
</main>
```

Comment: note for me: re-try to find the duplicate later